# Add Previous and Next to slider to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

This slider is working great:

http://pastebin.com/BxN8vbAt

One thing I want to add is a Prev and Next

Anyone know how to make the Prev/Next links work properly?:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opens Slide 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opens Slide 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opens Slide 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

*Resolved

Comment: Can you provide a demo of your code via http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class `link-prev` and class `link-next` to your previous and next links.

```
<a href="#" class="link-prev">Prev</a>
<a href="#" class="link-next">Next</a>
```

And to make a pager use the class `switcher` on your ul. You will not be able to have your previous and next links in the ul however.

```
<ul class="switcher"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! this was so simeple!